# Value error for CatboostRegressor with StratifiedKFold

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, catboost

I just started learning Catboost and tried to use CatboostRegressor with StratifiedKFold, but ran into error:

Here is the edited post with full block of codes and error for clarification. In addition, also tried with 
for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(fold.split(X,y)):
did not work though.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold,StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from catboost import Pool, CatBoostRegressor
fold=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True,random_state=42)

err = []
y_pred = []
for train_index, test_index in fold.split(X,y):
#for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(fold.split(X,y)):
    X_train, X_val = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_val = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    _train = Pool(X_train, label = y_train)
    _valid = Pool(X_val, label = y_val)

    cb = CatBoostRegressor(n_estimators = 20000, 
                     reg_lambda = 1.0,
                     eval_metric = 'RMSE',
                     random_seed = 42,
                     learning_rate = 0.01,
                     od_type = "Iter",
                     early_stopping_rounds = 2000,
                     depth = 7,
                     cat_features = cate,
                     bagging_temperature = 1.0)
    cb.fit(_train,cat_features=cate,eval_set = _valid, early_stopping_rounds = 2000, use_best_model = True, verbose_eval = 100) 

    p = cb.predict(X_val)
    print("err: ",rmsle(y_val,p))
    err.append(rmsle(y_val,p))
    pred = cb.predict(test_df)
    y_pred.append(pred)
predictions = np.mean(y_pred,0)
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-3a0df0c7b8d6> in <module>()
      7 err = []
      8 y_pred = []
----> 9 for train_index, test_index in fold.split(X,y):
     10 #for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(fold.split(X,y)):
     11     X_train, X_val = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
    333                 .format(self.n_splits, n_samples))
    334 
--> 335         for train, test in super().split(X, y, groups):
    336             yield train, test
    337 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-   packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
     87         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
     88         indices = np.arange(_num_samples(X))
---> 89         for test_index in self._iter_test_masks(X, y, groups):
     90             train_index = indices[np.logical_not(test_index)]
     91             test_index = indices[test_index]

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in _iter_test_masks(self, X, y, groups)
    684 
    685     def _iter_test_masks(self, X, y=None, groups=None):
--> 686         test_folds = self._make_test_folds(X, y)
    687         for i in range(self.n_splits):
    688             yield test_folds == i

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in _make_test_folds(self, X, y)
    639             raise ValueError(
    640                 'Supported target types are: {}. Got {!r instead.'.format(
--> 641                     allowed_target_types, type_of_target_y))
    642 
    643         y = column_or_1d(y)

ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error for a very *fundamental* reason from basic ML theory: stratification is defined only for *classification*, in order to ensure equal representation of all classes in the split; it is **meaningless** in regression. Reading closely the error message, you should be able to convince yourself that its meaning is that `'continous'` targets (i.e. regression) are not supported, only `'binary'` or `'multiclass'` (i.e. classification); and this is not some peculiarity of scikit-learn, but a fundamental issue indeed.

A relevant hint is also included in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) (emphasis added):

> Stratified K-Folds cross-validator
>
> Provides train/test indices to split data in train/test sets.
>
> This cross-validation object is a variation of KFold that returns
> stratified folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of
> samples for each **class**.

Here is a short demonstration, adapting the example from the documentation, but changing the targets `y` to be continuous (regression) instead of discrete (classification):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([0.1, 0.5, -1.1, 1.2]) # continuous targets, i.e. regression problem
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X,y):
    print("something")
[...]
ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.
```

So, simply speaking, you cannot actually use `StratifiedKFold` in your (regression) setting; change it to simple `KFold` and move on from there...

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be done, search for StratifiedKFoldReg

Look at this: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KnXujsQDvLZOgCRg_iis036cwffwZM2_?usp=sharing